# How do I navigate around Laravel installation issues. My developer uses Mac OS, and I have Ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, migration

Back story:I'm a jr. freelance dev, and I contracted a senior freelance dev to help with a Laravel project. He put everything on Github, and I downloaded it, so I can do a local installation of it. I think he's using a Macbook pro, and I'm using Lenovo w/ Ubuntu 18.04 installed (I think this might be a part of the problem...not sure).

I am having a hard time installing the Laravel project (I've looked at a number of Laravel installation tutorials from Git specifically, especially with databases). I've already contacted him, and I'm waiting on a reply, but in the meantime, I'd like to figure out the possible reasons that I'm can't get past this database migration issue.

So far, I've set up a mysql database on phpmyadmin/localhost with same database name, username, password, and collation as what's in the config/database.php file. I also made a .env file with the same information. In the database.php file, I noticed that within the mysql array, there's this key-value pair:

```
          'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'fake_db_name'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'boot'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'snoot'),
            **'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',**
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

With this line in particular, is that why I'm running into issues (shown below)? I'm on Ubuntu, but MAMP is in the directory (what the other deve uses). What does this even mean?

```
'unix_socket' => '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',
```

Secondly, when I run php artisan migrate, I get these errors:

```
   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = fake_db_name and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at /home/myname/Documents/02 - Fake/Fake/fake-folder/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664
    660|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    661|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    662|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    663|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 664|             throw new QueryException(
    665|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    666|             );
    667|         }
    668| 

  Exception trace:

  1   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
      /home/myname/Documents/02 - Fake/Fake/Fake-folder/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:31

  2   PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused")
      /home/myname/Documents/Fake/Fake/Fake-folder/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:27
```

Overall, I'm trying to figure out how to locally install a Laravel project with a considerable number of datatables, and could use some help.

Answer (score 1):

Both you and your mate should use [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/homestead#introduction) to work on the project - **don't use your physical machines (host machines)**. Homestead makes everything **host-environment agnostic**. It is a virtual environment so that both of you have a **consistent platform with no mismatch** in configuration.

When you use your host machine, each of you will have to configure local server, database connections and maybe PHP settings differently and that for sure will lead to issues in a long run.

Comment: Thank you. I saw that there was 'Homestead' in the filepath within the project in general, and wondered if that was an issue as well.